# Return value from list of lat / long based upon current geolocation ios app javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, geolocation

I have an App I want to expand to return some data from closest entry from a list of Lat/Longs (and 2 additional fields) based upon the user's current geolocation.  It's approx 5,000 entries large.  I would like to know the most efficient way to search this list based upon the current geolocation.  What would be the best approach to implement this?  It's an iOS based application using the Ionic Framework along with AngularJS.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't really need the most efficient way, just an algorithm that is sufficiently fast. For your data set of approx. 5000 entries, the trivial solution may very well be enough.

Once you have determined the user's current location, calculate the distance between it and each of the points on a sphere (earth). You could for example look into the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for that. Finding an existing JavaScript implementation should be possible.

After that, simply pick the lowest distance from the set.